# How to temporarily remove a variable from a loop?

Tags: python, excel, list

I have an excel document that I loop through a list of IP addresses and pings them. If an IP has an unheathly response, it will **stop the loop for a certain amount of time**.

I would like to be able to temporarily remove that IP from the loop so that the list can continue looping until it becomes heathly again and it can be put back into the list when that condition is met.

Example:

```
while True:
    get_ip() 

    # Ping each IP Address in the list
    for ip in ip_addr:
        response = os.popen(f"ping {ip} ").read()

        if "Request timed out." in response:
            print("Stops the loop for 30 seconds")
        ### This is where I would like to take the IP out and keep the loop going without it for 30 seconds ###
            time.sleep(30)
        
        else:
            print(ip, " is ONLINE")  # Prints IP and its status
```

Get IP from Excel and put it into a list function

```
# Gets the WAN 1 IP address from excel
def get_ip():
    global ip_addr

    # Loads spreadsheet
    getExcelSpreadsheet()

    # Create list to append IPs to
    ip_list = []

    # Takes all the values in a column and puts them in a list 'ip_list'
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=starting_row, min_col=2, max_row=ending_row, max_col=2):
        for cell in row:
            ip_list.append(cell.value)

    ip_addr = iter(ip_list)
```

To help with this, I can enumerate each IP with a unique variable and put them into a dictionary

```
ip_dict = {}
for enum, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2,max_row=4), 1):
    k = f'IP({enum})'
    v = row[0].value
    ip_dict[k] = v
```

And the output would look like so:

```
{'IP(1)': '8.8.8.8', 'IP(2)': '10.1.40.1', 'IP(3)': '10.1.30.1'}
```

How do I put this all together to do what I want?

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe add it to a queue a tuple as `(IP, current_time)`, and check every iteration if 30 seconds have passed since then. If so, pop it back in the list. You would have to make use of a `while len(ip_addr) > 0 and len(queue): > 0` loop and pop each IP once it has been dealt with.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal This is a good idea, how would that look like with my code as it stands? Specifically "popping it back into queue"

Comment: You don't need to "remove" it from the queue.  Just store a flag with it.  If the flag is set, then you check the timer and maybe skip it.  If the flag is not set, you handle it normally.

Comment: @TimRoberts So an IP, a flag _and_ a timer? I feel like a queue would be shorter and more readable.

Comment: More readable than a single list with a three-entry list?  I doubt it.  Any time you're moving an entry between multiple queues, it's an opportunity for error.